# Failed to mount disk at startup

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, linux-kernel

I have a 10.10 Xubuntu installed with the kernel 2.6.35-22 but for work I need to make a downgrade to 2.6.30.5, for that, I compiled the kernel with all modules I need (or so I think) and when loading, I get:

```
mount: mounting none on /dev failed: no such device 
W: devtmpfs not available, falling back to tmpfs for /dev
```

```
WARNING bootdevice may be renamed. Try root=/dev/hda1
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline )
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/sda1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

After that sends me to busybox and making cd on /dev does not appear any sda, hda or by-uuid/path/label

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing CONFIG_DEVTMPFS

Hand selecting modules is very difficult these days (I miss the 1.0 days). I would just use the default [Ubuntu kernel build system](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile/) to build one with "everything", wait forever for it to build, then move on to better activities.  :)

You could also just downgrade the kernel to a previous Ubuntu version if you can find the version you want. I can never remember how to do it but it is a question that has been answered many times in the past if you want to search.

Comment: Ok i have been trying everything you say (except as to download the kernel from git) unfortunately i could not get it to boot and CONFIG_DEVTMPFS not exist in this [kernel](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DEVTMPFS.html), has any other suggestions? i'm getting a little nervous with this

Comment: Have you tried one of the "build kernel" tutorials?  Like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=311158)